# Cannot deserialize the current JSON - DeserializeObject - Bad model

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, ienumerable

I try downloading data from API, but I get an error when `DeserializeObject`

I suppose I have a badly built model: `ObjectResponse`

but I can't think of how else to build it

I use Newtonsoft.Json

Controller

```cs
private async Task<Response<IEnumerable<ObjectResponse>>> GetItemsAsync(string uri)
{
    var result = await _client.GetStringAsync(uri);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<IEnumerable<ObjectResponse>>>(result);
}
```

in result I have:

> "{"success":true,"data":{"leasingItems":[],"suspectedItems":[]}}"

Models

```cs
public class Response<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectResponse
{
    public string[]? leasingItems { get; set; }
    public string[]? suspectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

> One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Swip.Core.DTO.SwipSearchSuspect]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'data.leasingItems', line 1, position 39.)

> Inner Exception 1:
> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Swip.Core.DTO.SwipSearchSuspect]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'data.leasingItems', line 1, position 39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property in the JSON was an `ObjectResponse` object, but not an `ObjectResponse` array.

Remove the `IEnumerable<>`.

```cs
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<ObjectResponse>>(result);
```

And apply the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm) attribute.

```cs
public class Response<T>
{
  [JsonProperty("success")]
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("data")]
  public T Data { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```